# Get the original name of uploaded files in streamlit

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I'm using streamlit to make a basic visualization app to compare two datasets, for that I'm using the following example made by Marc Skov from the streamlit gallery:

```
from typing import Dict

import streamlit as st


@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def get_static_store() -> Dict:
    """This dictionary is initialized once and can be used to store the files uploaded"""
    return {}


def main():
    """Run this function to run the app"""
    static_store = get_static_store()

    st.info(__doc__)
    result = st.file_uploader("Upload", type="py")
    if result:
        # Process you file here
        value = result.getvalue()

        # And add it to the static_store if not already in
        if not value in static_store.values():
            static_store[result] = value
    else:
        static_store.clear()  # Hack to clear list if the user clears the cache and reloads the page
        st.info("Upload one or more `.py` files.")

    if st.button("Clear file list"):
        static_store.clear()
    if st.checkbox("Show file list?", True):
        st.write(list(static_store.keys()))
    if st.checkbox("Show content of files?"):
        for value in static_store.values():
            st.code(value)


main()
```

This does work, but it is odd to compare datasets without been able to display their names.
The code does explicitly says that is not possible to get the file names using this method. But this is an example from 8 months ago, I wonder if is there another way to accomplish this now.

Answer (score 6):

In commit made on [9 July](https://github.com/sstm2/streamlit/commit/e7becc5ff1b4f5b43a7c7085fe1f693630c62a38) a slight modification of `file_uploader()` was made. It now returns a dict that contains:

- name key contains the uploaded file name
- data key contains a BytesIO or StringIO object

So you should be able to get the filename using `result.name` and the data using `result.data`.